# Selecting rows which do not exist for a specific user

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables (Users,Config,Fields,AvailableFields)

User's relevant schema is

```
UserID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY_KEY
```

Config's relevant schema is

```
ConfigID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
UserID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (User.UserID)
```

Field's relevant schema is

```
FieldID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
AvailableFieldID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (AvailableFields.AvailableFieldsID)
ConfigID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (Config.ConfigID)
```

AvailableFields relevant schema is

```
AvailableFieldID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

I am trying to return all of the Available fields for a specific user which they do not have in their Fields table.

Is there a way to do this with a join?

I cannot see a way as the only link between the template AvailableFields table is AvailableFieldID which is a foreign key inside Fields table.

Comment: Do you mean to find available fields from `AvailableFields` that are not mapped to a particular user?

Comment: Yes exactly @DarkKnight

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `INNER JOIN` function with the `Config` as the first table and `Field` as the second table to get all users with a `Config` entry. Then use `RIGHT JOIN` to select all the available field entries and leave out users with no available field entry.

Then all of the select with `WHERE AvailableFields.AvailableFieldID IS NULL`. This joins the table with all results from `Field`/`Config` table. Then it selects the users who do not have an `AvailableFields` entry.

**Code:**

```
SELECT *
FROM Config
INNER JOIN Field ON Config.ConfigID = Field.ConfigID
RIGHT JOIN AvailableFields ON AvailableFields.AvailableFieldID = Field.AvailableFieldID
WHERE Field.UserID IS NULL
```

This will return all entries in `AvailableFields` that don't have a corresponding `Field` entry (i.e. No users) .

Answer (score 0):

I think the most intuitive way would be to use `NOT IN` with a subquery:

```
SELECT * from AvailableField
WHERE AvailableField.AvailableFieldId NOT IN
    (SELECT AvailableFieldId FROM Field
    INNER JOIN Config ON Config.ConfigId = Field.ConfigId
    WHERE Config.UserId = ?)
```

Where `?` is a placeholder for the ID of the user you are interested in.

If you are performance-sensitive and are using large tables, multiple joins would be better than this subquery approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use combination of `INNER JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`

```
SELECT af.AvailableFieldID
from Config C 
    inner join Field F on F.configid = c.configid
    right join AvailableFields af on F.AvailableFieldID = af.AvailableFieldID
where f.AvailableFieldID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    SELECT AvailableFieldID FROM AvailableFields 
    WHERE AvailableFieldID  NOT IN ( 
           SELECT  AvailableFieldID from Field f INNER JOIN Config c ON f.ConfigID  = c.ConfigID INNER JOIN UserID u on u.UserID = c.UserID
           WHERE UserID = "Your condition")
```

I hope resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplified version answering your question's requirements:

```
        select af.AvailableFieldID 
        from AvailableFields af  -- all available fields
        left join (select distinct f.AvailableFieldID 
                   from Config c
                   join Fields f
                   on c.ConfigID = f.ConfigID
                   where c.UserID = @UserID) AS UserHas -- the fields the user has
        on af.AvailableFieldID = UserHas.AvailableFieldID
        where UserHas.AvailableFieldID is null -- a field match for the user isn't there
```

This will also return AvailableFieldID that are not in a Config.

The version you probably want b/c it can be multi-users:

```
    select u.UserID, af.AvailableFieldID 
    from Users u  -- all users
    cross join AvailableFields af  -- all fields
    left join (select distinct f.AvailableFieldID, c.UserID 
               from Config c
               join Fields f
               on c.ConfigID = f.ConfigID) AS UserHas -- the fields each user has
     on u.UserID = UserHas.UserID
        and af.AvailableFieldID = UserHas.AvailableFieldID
     where UserHas.AvailableFieldID is null -- a field match for the user isn't there
           and (@UserID is null or u.UserID = @UserID) -- option to limit it to one user
```